# How to check if sql server connection has uncommitted data

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

My API receives a connection which should not have any un-commited data. I need to throw exception in that case.

Comment: It depends on your API, if it takes care of uncommitted changes/transactions.

Comment: No I can't handle uncommited data It will corrupt the data. That's why I was thinking of throwing exception in that case.

Comment: Why not accept a connection string (or moral equivalent) rather than a connection? A connection that *your* code opens can be in any state that *you* want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can take control manually, see [How to start a transaction in JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940648/how-to-start-a-transaction-in-jdbc)

Or you can leave the transaction handling (including deadlocks) to the procedural code on the server. You haven't given us much to go on in terms of scope.