# Unable to insert data in foreign key table in jdbc prepared statement

Tags: mysql, jdbc, javabeans

I'm new to this. I'm having two tables. `registrationtable` and `logintable`, where `registerationid` is primary key in `registrationtable` and foreign key in `logintable` where `registerationid` is *Auto_Increment* in `registrationtable`. I'm able to insert in `registrationtable` but not in `logintable`. I'm using `PreparedStatement` and having `Bean` class. Please anybody can help me.
Thank you in advance for helping.

```
try {               
        PreparedStatement preparedstatement=connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO registrationtable(firstname,lastname,dob,address,city,state,mob) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        preparedstatement.setString(1,bean.getFirstName());
        preparedstatement.setString(2,bean.getLastName());
        preparedstatement.setString(3,bean.getDOB());
        preparedstatement.setString(4,bean.getAddress());
        preparedstatement.setString(5,bean.getCity());
        preparedstatement.setString(6,bean.getState());
        preparedstatement.setString(7,bean.getMobile());

        System.out.println("Dao Rgisteration : "+bean.getFirstName());
        preparedstatement.executeUpdate();

        ResultSet resultset=preparedstatement.getGeneratedKeys();
        resultset.next();
        int autoGeneratedKeyRegisteration = resultset.getInt(1);

        preparedstatement.close();
    //  resultset=preparedstatement.executeQuery("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS last_id FROM registerationtable");



        String sql="INSERT INTO logintable(registerationid,username,password) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'xyz@gmail.com','xyzabc123')";
        PreparedStatement preparedstatement1=connection.prepareStatement(sql,PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        preparedstatement1.setInt(1,bean.getRegistrationId());
        preparedstatement1.setString(2, bean.getUsername());
        preparedstatement1.setString(3, bean.getPassword());
        System.out.println("Dao Login : "+bean.getUsername());
        preparedstatement1.executeUpdate();

        ResultSet resultset1=preparedstatement1.getGeneratedKeys();
        if(resultset1.next()){
        int autoGeneratedkeyLogin=resultset1.getInt(1);
        }
        resultset1=preparedstatement1.executeQuery("SELECT registerationid FROM logintable WHERE registerationid=LAST_INSERT_ID()");
        System.out.println(resultset);
        preparedstatement1.close();
    } catch(Exception e){e.getMessage();}finally{
        try{
            connection.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){ex.getMessage();}
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, I advice to make those inserts within a transaction:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5723862/3323777

And use `getGeneratedKeys` instead LAST_INSERT_ID:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1915197/3323777

LAST_INSERT_ID has some caveats and limitations:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21188