# How setting Auto Commit off, helps to start a transaction in JDBC?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, database, jdbc

Many articles and documents says that by setting Auto Commit off, You can start a transaction in JDBC. [This Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940648/how-to-start-a-transaction-in-jdbc) also ask same question but It doesn't answer to the question and just said:

> Changing the auto-commit mode triggers a commit of the current transaction (if one is active).

Ok. but next?

for finding an answer, I searched and found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> - **Autocommit transactions:**
>
> Each individual statement is a transaction.
>
> - **Explicit transactions:**
>
> Each transaction is explicitly started with the
>   BEGIN TRANSACTION statement and explicitly ended with a COMMIT or
>   ROLLBACK statement.
>
> - **Implicit transactions:**
>
> A new transaction is implicitly started when the prior transaction completes, but each transaction is explicitly
>   completed with a COMMIT or ROLLBACK statement.

And then I found [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html):

> **Committing Transactions**
>
> After the auto-commit mode is disabled, no SQL statements are committed until you call the method commit explicitly. ***All statements executed after the previous call to the method `commit` are included in the current transaction and committed together as a unit.***

Therefore I conclude that after the auto-commit mode is disabled, we are in Implicit mode and we also know that for disabling auto-commit, a COMMIT statement has been run so after setting the Auto-commit off, we've started a new transaction.

Can we draw such a conclusion based on these cases? is it a right conclusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot. In JDBC, auto-commit only governs when a transaction is to end. A driver is expected to start a transaction when it is needed. Specifically the [JDBC 4.3 specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr221/index3.html) says in section *10.1 Transaction Boundaries and Auto-commit*:

> When to start a new transaction is a decision made implicitly by
>   either the JDBC driver or the underlying data source. Although some
>   data sources implement an explicit “begin transaction” statement,
>   there is no JDBC API to do so. Typically, a new transaction is started
>   when the current SQL statement requires one and there is no
>   transaction already in place. Whether or not a given SQL statement
>   requires a transaction is also specified by SQL:2003.
>
> The `Connection` attribute *auto-commit* specifies when to end
>   transactions. Enabling auto-commit causes a transaction commit after
>   each individual SQL statement as soon as that statement is complete.
>   The point at which a statement is considered to be “complete” depends
>   on the type of SQL statement as well as what the application does
>   after executing it:
>
> - For Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements such as Insert, Update, Delete, and DDL statements, the statement is complete as soon
>     as it has finished executing.
> - For `Select` statements, the statement is complete when the associated result set is closed.
> - For `CallableStatement` objects or for statements that return multiple results, the statement is complete when all of the associated
>     result sets have been closed, and all update counts and output
>     parameters have been retrieved.

In other words, when you call `connection.setAutoCommit(false)` no transaction will be started. Only when a statement is executed (or another operation that requires a transaction), a transaction will be started if there is no active transaction.